# How to add white space to visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I'd like to add white space to visualforce page I created, so that there is much more white space under Force.com Dashboards.

[image: Picture of Picture]

For example, I have the below visualforce code, and I've tried to add the white space by setting the body to min-height: 2000px;

```
<apex:page >

<html>
<head>

    <title>Salesforce Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" media="screen" />


</head>
<style>
    body {

    min-height: 2000px;
    }
</style>

<body>
<h1 class="title">Force.com Dashboards</h1>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is placed inside a table with id "bodyTable". By styling that table with height you can add some space.

```
<apex:page>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Salesforce Dashboard</title>
</head>
<style>
    #bodyTable {
        min-height: 2000px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h1 class="title">Force.com Dashboards</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or, similarly, just put your content in a div, and style the div with a minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty `<p></p>` tag, or if you'd like to go by lines you can just use `<br />`.

**Example:**

```
<head>

    <title>Salesforce Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" media="screen" />


</head>
/* as this is a Visualforce page you don't need a body Tag, or even the HTML Tag */



<h1 class="title">Force.com Dashboards</h1>
<br />
<br />


</apex:page>
```